# Case statement not executing second case

Tags: sql, oracle

I need your assistance with the below query. Could you please assist?

Below are sample records from the Oracle database:

id:

```
L7985W6W7W5HJYR5 
LJHGTIKFF89EE7HJJU7 
LIUH789KEHD7W9JHF
LYUEJDJ8F2NIBRANCH
LOI9DDH7E38BRANCH
L8908HYS6WIBRANCH
PJHS79209KJSJYIEJHSV12
```

My intention is if `b.branch_id` begins with `L` then it will remove leading zeroes and strip characters but if `b.branch_id` ends with `‘%BRANCH%'` then I would like it to merge with another field but is not working. The first part is working,  if it begins with `L` then it works but somehow never executes the `‘%BRANCH%'` part.

```
Select distinct b.branch_id,
b.branch_date

CASE 
 WHEN b.branch_id like L%'
  THEN TRIM(substr((TO_CHAR(TRIM(LEADING 0 FROM b.branch_id))),-10))
   WHEN b.branch_id like ‘%BRANCH%'
     THEN substr(b.branch_loc,2,9) || substr(i.branch_name,1,9)
       END AS BRANCH_INFO

from tbl_brach b
JOIN tbl_branch_info i
on b.branch_id = i.branch_id_key 

where b.branch_id like L%'
```

Comment: If you want only want to get stuff with branch at the end, you should use `like '%BRANCH'`

Comment: Why would you expect it go into the second branch when it matches the first branch's condition?

Comment: Those are case expressions, not case statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/expressions004.htm):

> In a simple CASE expression, Oracle Database searches for the first WHEN ... THEN pair for which *expr* is equal to *comparison_expr* and returns *return_expr*.
>   ...
>   For a simple CASE expression, the database evaluates each *comparison_expr* value only before comparing it to *expr*, rather than evaluating all *comparison_expr* values before comparing any of them with *expr*.

You need to arrange the case statement so the most restrictive rule is matched first, otherwise it is never reached:

```
CASE
  WHEN b.branch_id like ‘L%BRANCH%'
    THEN substr(b.branch_loc,2,9) || substr(i.branch_name,1,9)
  WHEN b.branch_id like L%'
    THEN TRIM(substr((TO_CHAR(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM b.branch_id))),-10))
END AS BRANCH_INFO
```

You could also say

```
  WHEN b.branch_id LIKE 'L%' AND b.branch_id LIKE '%BRANCH%' THEN
```

but it's simpler to combine into a single `LIKE` pattern.

Your query also has a `where` clause that makes the `L%` in the case expression redundant, but I'm not sure if that is temporary. If it is then you may want an `ELSE` to handle all values that don't start with L, unless you want them to (implicitly) be null.

As Laurel noted, if you want the value to end with 'BRANCH' then you don't want the final wildcard % sign, as that will also match if there are more characters after BRANCH. You don't have that in your sample data.