# I'm getting the result as 1 in the output part. why it not executed second case ?? Explain this statement in detail

Tags: sql

```
SELECT  
    CASE 
        WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 1
        WHEN 1 = 1 THEN 2
        ELSE 0 
    END
```

Output: `1`

Why does this `CASE` not return `2` as the result?

Comment: mysql or (ms) sql-server or oracle db? please remove unrelated tags

Comment: Please [edit] the question to only tag a single RDBMS. Do not spam tags for multiple RDBMS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36926656/case-statement-not-executing-second-case

Answer (score 3):

As soon as the first condition is met (1 = 1), the result is being returned. Other conditions aren't evaluated so ... that's why you don't get 2 as result.

Answer (score 0):

The case clause is executed as If...elseif.. else condition. whenever the first condition in when satisfied, then result will show.

So first When (1=1) condition satisfy and give the then result always.

Try this below queries to know more

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN 1
    WHEN 1=1 THEN 2
    ELSE 0 END

SELECT  CASE WHEN 1=2 THEN 1
    WHEN 1=3 THEN 2
    ELSE 0 END
```